# Reducing Row Height in a Longtable

Tags: longtable

How can we change the line spacing in a long-table? I used package `setspace` and `\linestretch` command, but its not working. Minimal Example is attached.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{stepspace}

\makeatletter

\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.8}


\lipsum{1}

\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{135pt}>{\raggedright}p{135pt}r}

\caption{dfkg kdlfgj dfjkg dfklgj sd}

\hline 

\textbf{Country} & \textbf{District} & \textbf{Amount }\textbf{\scriptsize ('000'USD)}\tabularnewline

\hline 

\endhead

Afghanistan & L & 6\tabularnewline

\hline 
Australia & K & 2,9\tabularnewline

\hline 
Austria & I & 3\tabularnewline

\hline 
Bahrain & K & 3\tabularnewline
 & L & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
Belgium & K & 1\tabularnewline
 & L & 2\tabularnewline

\hline 
Canada & I & 99,965\tabularnewline
 & K & 9\tabularnewline
 & L & 1\tabularnewline

\hline 
Cayman I & I & 2\tabularnewline
 & Ka & 1\tabularnewline

\hline 
\textbf{Grand Total} &  & \textbf{2}\tabularnewline

\hline 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can change the parameter `\arraystretch` via `\renewcommand`; the default value is `1.0`.

Comment: You can use `\setstretch{0.8}` just before the long table.

Answer (score 13):

First, in a LaTeX document it's best not to modify low-level TeX commands such as `\baselineskip` directly. Second, if you use the `setspace` package, use its `\setstretch` command -- or, equivalently, commands such as `\onehalfspacing` or `\doublespacing` -- to organize the line spacing for entire document parts. Note, though, that even if you've set `\onehalfspacing` for your document, line spacing in `tabular`-like  environments will still be single-spaced.

To fine-tune the line spacing in `tabular`-like and `array`-like environments, start with the `\arraystretch` command. E.g., to reduce the leading of a given `tabular` environment by 50%, you could type

```
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
```

between `\begin{table}` and `\begin{tabular}{...}`.

For a `longtable` environment, you would type

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
\begin{longtable}{...}
% longtable headers, footers, and body
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
```

The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements serve to keep the scope of `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}` local to the group.

Of course, if you want the redefinition of `\arraystretch` to have global or document-wide scope, just insert the instruction in the preamble.

Comment: Is there any way I can define the `\arraystretch` only for the content rows, but omit this setting for the header and footer rows?

Comment: @Socrates - As as I know, the answer to your question is "No". However, I'm not the ultimate expert on this subject. I would like to encourage you to post a *new query* to explore exactly this topic. Thanks.

Comment: Already done, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451581/custom-cell-spacing-in-longtable