# Custom cell spacing in longtable

Tags: longtable, cell, cellspace

Is it possible to define custom cell spacing in `longtable`?

Example:

```
\begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{8cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{8cm}|}
    ...
    one & two\\
    three & four\\
    five & six\\
\end{longtable}
```

I would like to have the cells `three` and `four` to be 3cm high while the other cells remain as they are. How would I do that?

Comment: I did find a way to do it using `\rule{0pt}{25pt}` at every line beginning. Not quite so pretty, but as a workaround it does the trick. I am still open to better solutions, if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `longtblr` enviroment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), it is easy to set row heights.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {My First Long Table},
  label = {not:long},
]{
  colspec = {|Q[l,8cm]|Q[l,8cm]|},
  hlines, vlines,
}
  one   & two  \\
  \SetRow{3cm,rowsep=0pt} three & four \\
  five  & six \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]