# How to create a table with merged columns and rows

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, covers

I'm new to latex, and I'm trying to create a cover for a report, that I use in word, but I'm struggling with latex.
Could someone help me?

I have tried the multicolumn but I didn't manage to organize the sizes of each cell, I need to merge some columns and some rows like in the image:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=10mm,
 top=10mm,
 }
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{43pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
\hline

Logo 1 & Logo 2 & TEXT 1 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{TITLE}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{TEXT 2}
TEXT 3 & TEXT 4 & DATE \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{ABSTRACT}
AUTHOR 1 & AUTHOR 2   & TYPE \\
APROVED & COMPANY  \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the tabularray package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it is not clear, if "XXX" will be insert by hand or is part of table
- in the latter case should  from table code remove all `\qquad` and "xxx2
- your table is complex and it seems that only with `tabularray` can be (at least simple) to write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            left=10mm,
            top=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 
% \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{43pt}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={*{3}{X[l]}},
             rowsep=5pt,
             row{1} = {c},
             hspan=minimal}
Logo 1  & Logo 2    & TEXT 1                \\
\SetCell[c=3]{c}    TITLE                 \\
\SetCell[c=2, r=4]{h,j}   TITLE 2

\lipsum[66]
        &       & REF. xx:\par\qquad   TEXT 3      \\
        &       & REF. xx:\par\qquad   TEXT 4      \\
        &       & DATE:   \par\qquad   xx.xx.xxxx  \\
        &       & REVIEW  \par\qquad   x          \\
\SetCell[c=3]{j}   ABSTRACT:

    \lipsum[1]                              \\
AUTHOR 1\par    \qquad   xx    
        & AUTHOR 2\par\qquad   xx  
                & \SetCell[r=2]{l,h} TYPE\par   
                    \qquad   INFORM         \\
APROVED\par\qquad   xx
        & COMPANY\par\qquad   xx
                &                           \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's almost perfect, the only issue is the size of the table, which should be fixed to \pageheight, but I'll figure out where to set that =D

Comment: @JenifferBarreto, width of table is equal to text width. If you like to have some rows higher, this you should mentioned in question. Also, how height they should be. For row height see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451581/