# Table with height an exact multiple of constant

Tags: tables, tabularx

How can I create a table where each row is *exactly* the multiple of a constant (in this example, it is 3cm)?

Text within a row can wrap multiple lines, but if the height of the row after wrapping exceeds 3cm, it should increase to the next multiple of 3cm.

I do not know ahead of time how many rows or lines each entry takes up. The tex file is generated dynamically. The height will have to be dynamically generated in TeX. At the moment I am using Python to estimate how many lines each row takes up based on the number of characters and setting the height that way.

[image: Example of table layout]

I've tried using `tabularx` and adjusting `arraystretch` with no success:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|p{5cm}|}
  \hline
  Row 1 & Content of row 1. This might be a long text that needs to wrap onto the next line. \\
  \hline
  Row 2 & Content of row 2. \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

I've also tried making a `vbox` with a height calculated from an expression related to the height of a `strutbox`/`parbox` although I was unable to get it working or even compiling:

```
\newcommand{\dynamicrow}[1]{\vbox to \dimexpr2cm * \ceil*{(\ht\strutbox+#1)/2cm}\relax{\vfil\parbox[t][\dimexpr2cm * \ceil*{(\ht\strutbox+#1)/2cm}\relax][c]{\linewidth}{#1}\vfil}}
```

The table entries would then be inserted as

```
\dynamicrow{Content of row 1. This might be a long text that needs to wrap onto the next line.} & Example text \\
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE community, Se if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451581/  custom-cell-spacing-in-longtable can help you (as starting point).

Comment: Usually questions are closed when NO code is given, demonstrating your approach, trials and obsticles. Just posting an intended result is often percieved as a "do-it-for-me-task" ... which is not our purpose. // So kindly post your relevant code next time, and make sure: it compiles, leaves out what's irrelevant for your problem, still shows your problem. Thank you

Comment: I didn't think posting a MWE was worth it nor would it benefit the community because I knew my approach was entirely wrong, so it wasn't so much that the existing code needed to be fixed, but rather required an entirely new strategy. I have posted my attempts.

Comment: @JamesS Posting a MWE is _always_ useful, because who wants to help you has something to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another example based on saved boxes--the way to obtained the current height of multiple multi lined paragraphs.

I have used a little different approach to build a long table based on `longtblr` from `tabularray` package. The fixed height is obtained by: calculating the next closest multiple of a constant; and creating a invisible item of the size, a vertical rule of 0 width. By the way, I applied `longtblr` because tables in `tabularray` have a much simplified approach to apply a macro for selected cells, as well as formatting is much easier.

Currently, there is a limit that texts in affected cells, those for which `\processcell{}` is applied for, require inner formatting inside the macro `\processcell` in the `\parbox`.

Below is one example for cells whose height is fixed to a multiple of 2 cm but this can be change by altering the macro `\mtplconst`:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}

\newcommand\mtplconst{2}   % Multiple of 2cm
\NewDocumentCommand\processcell{m}{%
  \sbox1{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
  \dimen0 = \fpeval{
    ceil((\ht1+\dp1)/\mtplconst/72.27*2.54)*\mtplconst*72.27/2.54
  }pt%
  \rule[-\dimexpr\dimen0-0.7\baselineskip]{0pt}{\dimen0}\usebox1}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Test},
    label = {tab:test},
  ]{
      width = \linewidth,
      colspec = {Q[2cm,l] X Q[2cm,l]},
      row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
      cell{2-Z}{2} = {cmd=\processcell},
      hline{3-Y} = {wd=\cmidrulewidth},
      rowhead = 1,
    }
    \toprule
    Head  & Column        & Column \\
    \midrule
    Row 1 & \kant[2][1]   & Short sentence. \\
    Row 2 & \kant[1][1-3] & Short sentence. \\
    Row 3 & \kant[3][1-2] & Short sentence. \\
    Row 4 & \kant[3][3]   & Short sentence. \\
    Row 5 & \kant[3][4]   & Short sentence. \\
    Row 6 & \kant[1][4]   & Short sentence. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I ended up replacing the constants 72.27 and 2.54 which are (approximate) unit conversion factors and just went with `ceil((\ht1+\dp1)/\mtplconst)*\mtplconst` and set the units of `\mtplconst` to be in pt. I also had to add `\SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt}` and remove the 0.7 factor (with just 1) to get the exact heights needed.

Comment: Make sure other tables look OK because `\SetTblrInner{}` is a global setting affecting all tables in your code defined in `tabularray`, while `rowsep=0pt` setting seems rather specific to this particular table.  Instead, I would rather insert `row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},` to even exclude the heading.

Comment: The `0.7\baselineskip` is the height of `\strut` you can insert in tables. Check this code: `\the\ht\strutbox, \the\dimexpr0.7\baselineskip` and get the same numbers. However, in your case, that specific height may give you better results.

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't show a MWE, I will only include some code that demonstrate in principle what you can do. The basic idea is to place each of your table entries into a minipage, whose height is computed dynamically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\threecm
\setlength\threecm{3cm}
\newsavebox{\innertextbox}

\newcommand{\scaletothreecm}[1]{\sbox{\innertextbox}%
    {\begin{minipage}[b]{5cm} \raggedright #1\end{minipage}}%
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr \numexpr (\ht\innertextbox + \threecm/2)/\threecm * \threecm \relax sp\relax][t]{5cm}%
    \usebox{\innertextbox}\end{minipage}}}


\begin{document}
\scaletothreecm{Short text} \the\ht\innertextbox

\scaletothreecm{Explanation: \begin{enumerate}
    \item We first build a box with the specified width (5cm chosen arbitrarily) and the given material. This box is saved and not used. 
    \item We then build a new minipage with a specified height. This height is computed from the height of the original material. Since the division operation rounds to the nearest integer, to make it round \emph{up} instead, we first add to the measured height half of the unit.
    \item Inside the minipage we use the saved material.
    \item For illustration we wrap the whole thing in a fbox so you can see the extra space reserved.\end{enumerate}}
\the\ht\innertextbox

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remark.** Notice that in the second example, the baseline of the box is set at the bottom of the text of the inner box. This is an artifact of us using `\usebox` to print the content. Alternatively, you can just replace the `\usebox` with `\raggedright #1` and with the existing specification the baseline of the adjacent text (namely the amount 302.94444pt) will be aligned with the top line of text.