# How to reduce spacing between the rows in the latex longtable

Tags: overleaf

Hello I am having this code that results in the multiple page longtable generation. However, I wish to reduce the spacing between the row a bit, without compromising the font of the letters. I tried couple of options that are commented in my code. Does anyone know how to achieve it?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{c c c} 
\caption{A simple longtable example} 
\label{tab:61_analogs}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}\\
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}\\
%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}\\

\hline
\textbf{Compound ID} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Compound ID} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
25019940 & 0.58 & 0.47 \\
5164097 & 0.66 & 0.48 \\
1738866 & 0.62 & 0.47 \\
20105225 & 0.62 & 0.49 \\
3110202 & 0.75 & 0.45 \\
3110206 & 0.73 & 0.62 \\
4867157 & 0.69 & 0.54 \\
4304409 & 0.76 & 0.54 \\
5151381 & 0.76 & 0.49 \\
3101013 & 0.73 & 0.53 \\
3100996 & 0.71 & 0.53 \\
3101001 & 0.71 & 0.36 \\
19165041 & 0.60 & 0.55 \\
74982828 & 0.95 & 0.59 \\
2959312 & 0.62 & 0.42 \\
25287769 & 0.54 & 0.42 \\
25287770 & 0.54 & 0.51 \\
5222294 & 0.65 & 0.60 \\
1256772 & 0.67 & 0.59 \\
5080634 & 0.66 & 0.59 \\
1146140 & 0.69 & 0.35 \\
5081393 & 0.58 & 0.41 \\
3463344 & 0.63 & 0.49 \\
3649210 & 0.73 & 0.49 \\
3101002 & 0.73 & 0.48 \\
3100991 & 0.68 & 0.39 \\
100382946 & 0.54 & 0.41 \\
100232025 & 0.53 & 0.35 \\
124451668 & 0.58 & 0.48 \\
3720795 & 0.67 & 0.59 \\
16678941 & 0.54 & 0.66 \\
24593477 & 0.63 & 0.65 \\
53198065 & 0.68 & 0.48 \\
4054374 & 0.64 & 0.45 \\
4573030 & 0.70 & 0.66 \\
46199646 & 0.43 & 0.41 \\
1261915 & 0.65 & 0.53 \\
51065402 & 0.57 & 0.47 \\
4313682 & 0.63 & 0.46 \\
40732500 & 0.70 & 0.46 \\
40732501 & 0.70 & 0.65 \\
11497983 & 0.64 & 0.52 \\
20933064 & 0.61 & 0.43 \\
4387920 & 0.63 & 0.47 \\
4575072 & 0.65 & 0.42 \\
40462013 & 0.55 & 0.42 \\
40462014 & 0.55 & 0.67 \\
28790638 & 0.73 & 0.67 \\
28790635 & 0.73 & 0.60 \\
51134141 & 0.63 & 0.66 \\
26351270 & 0.65 & 0.57 \\
16194825 & 0.62 & 0.71 \\
26324089 & 0.68 & 0.55 \\
125980034 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
42176161 & 0.69 & 0.48 \\
42176160 & 0.68 & 0.67 \\
24569294 & 0.64 & 0.44 \\
3101014 & 0.71 & 0.48 \\
3587610 & 0.71 & 0.49 \\
3100992 & 0.68 & 0.49 \\
995167 & 0.64 & 0.44 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176886/197451

Comment: Oh, so the trick is the placement. Thanks, it works for me too.

Comment: unrelated but never place `longtable` in a `center` environment